# write period index as a single value timestamp to parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a date `9999-12-31`. By default Pandas does not support the timestamp for this date. However I need to write it as timestamp to `parquet` file.

As a workaround, Pandas documentation proposes to use `period` to handle such date. However I cannot write it directly to `parquet` as it causes error `Not supported to convert PeriodArray to 'timestamp[us]' type` when I do it like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Period('9999-12-31', 'D')], columns=['Date'])
df.to_parquet('output_date.parquet', schema=pa.schema([('Date', pa.timestamp("us"))]))
```

I was trying to get a single value from this period

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Period('9999-12-31', 'D')], columns=['Date'])
df = df.iloc[0,:].to_frame().transpose()
df.to_parquet('output_date.parquet', schema=pa.schema([('Date', pa.timestamp("us"))]))
```

However even there is still a `PeriodArray` error.

And when I try to convert it to timestamp I get the normal timestamp error

```
print(df.iloc[0].values[0].to_timestamp()) # Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00
```

How can I write it to parquet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is fundamentally rooted in the fact that `Parquet` and `Pandas` libraries have differing upper bounds for dates they can handle. `Pandas` uses `numpy datetime64` data types that support a larger range, while `Parquet` uses `Timestamp` data types which do not handle such large dates.

One workaround would be to store the dates as strings and parse them back into date types when you read the data.

Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

# Create your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Period('9999-12-31', 'D')], columns=['Date'])

# Convert the period to string format
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)

# Save to parquet
df.to_parquet('output_date.parquet', schema=pa.schema([('Date', pa.string())]))
```

You can then parse the dates back to datetime format when you read the data.

```
# Reading the parquet file
df = pd.read_parquet('output_date.parquet')

# Converting the string back to date format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

print(df)
```

Please note that the `coerce` argument in `pd.to_datetime` will replace out-of-bounds dates with `NaT` (Not a Time) - this won't be a problem if you ensure that your date is within the valid range for pandas Timestamps before converting it back from string.

If you don't want the invalid dates to turn into `NaT`, you can use `pd.Period` instead of `pd.to_datetime` during the conversion, keeping in mind that this will return period objects instead of timestamp:

```
# Converting the string back to period format
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, 'D'))
This approach will ensure that your data is preserved in the Parquet file and can be read back accurately, albeit with some additional steps for conversion.
```

Comment: The thing is that "9999" date is not within the valid range for Pandas so I have to use Period, but I have to write it as a timestamp (so that parquet file will have a timestamp type), but I can't do that because converting it to timestamp causes error